# Superuser for Google Colab Notebooks

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, superuser

I wanted to use to add some python packages using `pip` in my Google Colab Notebook terminal and also set my environment variable(a JSON file). 
Where can I find a terminal so that I can do these tasks?
Is it even possible to run Google Colab Notebook as a superuser?

Answer (score 3):

Colab notebooks execute as root on ephemeral VMs. You can run `pip install` and configure environment variables like so:

Pip install:

```
!pip install -q matplotlib-venn
```

Environment variables:

```
import os
os.environ['YOUR_VARIABLE'] = 'value'
```

Did you encounter a particular error attempting to do something specific?